# How to netcat all the files in my directory?

Tags: linux, command-line, netcat

I have a directory of files I'd like to netcat to another machine.

For one, I use

```
nc <ip> <port> < sample.fls
```

But if I have a directory of

```
sample1.fls
sample2.fls
sample3.fls
sample4.fls
sample5.fls
sample6.fls
```

How can I netcat all these files with one command?

Comment: Tar'ing the files would be one way I can think of, the other would be to script it in a loop.

Answer (score 18):

On receiver, go to destination directory and execute:

```
nc -l $tcp_port |tar xf -
```

then on sender:

```
cd sourcedirectory
tar cf - . | nc $destination_host $tcp_port
```